# Hasura metadata export fields sort orders

Tags: metadata, hasura

When we execute `hasura metadata export` depending on which developer executes the command, we get different field sort orders. This generates a lot of conflicts, changes in the code.

Any idea how to fix this?

Sometimes it's:

```yaml
table:
  schema: public
  name: cd_site
object_relationships:
```

sometimes its

```yaml
table:
  name: cd_site
  schema: public
object_relationships:
```

More details in these pictures.

[image]
[image]